# How can I prevent image duplication while using drag and drop in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

My friends and I have been working on a simple program to drag and drop busses (off to the side) into parking spots. The program works fine without images, but when images are assigned as background images, they duplicate when dragged into a different spot (the image is not transferring with the div text). We've also tried to just have a image nested in the div rather than a background image, but that also did not work. This is our first time using drag and drop functions in HTML.

Here's what our HTML and JS look like and a link to running the current program that can demonstrate the error:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <div class="parent">
      <div id="div1" class = "target" data-name = "left" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div2" class = "target" data-name = "left" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div3" class = "target" data-name = "left" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div4" class = "target" data-name = "left" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>

      <div id="div5" class = "target" data-name = "down" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div6" class = "target" data-name = "down" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div7" class = "target" data-name = "down" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div8" class = "target" data-name = "down" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>

      <div id="div9" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div10" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div11" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div12" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div13" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div14" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div15" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div16" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div17" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div18" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div19" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div20" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div21" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      <div id="div22" class = "target" data-name = "right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>
      
      <div id="div23"> Lane 3 </div>
      <div id="div24"> Lane 2 </div>
      <div id="div25"> Lane 1</div>
      <div id="div26"> BUILDING 4 </div>
      <div id="div27"> BUILDING 3 </div>
      <div id="div28"> BUILDING 2 </div>
      <div id="div29"> PARKING </div>

      <div id="busSpot1" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      </div>
      <div id="busSpot2" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot3" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot4" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot5" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot6" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot7" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot8" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot9" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot10" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot11" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot12" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot13" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot14" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot15" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot16" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot17" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot18" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot19" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot20" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot21" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot22" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot23" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot24" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot25" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot26" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot27" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot28" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot29" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot30" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot31" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
      <div id="busSpot32" class = "target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>

      <div id="bus1" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Boonton</div>
      <div id="bus2" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Bloom</div>
      <div id="bus3" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Butler</div>
      <div id="bus4" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Chat</div>
      <div id="bus5" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >DOV</div>
      <div id="bus6" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >HP</div>
      <div id="bus7" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >J-Hop</div>
      <div id="bus8" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >J-OR</div>
      <div id="bus9" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >JTI</div>
      <div id="bus10" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >LP</div>
      <div id="bus11" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Madison</div>
      <div id="bus12" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Mend</div>
      <div id="bus13" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Mont 1</div>
      <div id="bus14" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Mont 2</div>
      <div id="bus15" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Mont 3</div>
      <div id="bus16" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Morris</div>
      <div id="bus17" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Mt. O</div>
      <div id="bus18" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >MH (Dorene)</div>
      <div id="bus19" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >MH (Bennanh)</div>
      <div id="bus20" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >MH (Carlos)</div>
      <div id="bus21" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >MH (Lillian)</div>
      <div id="bus22" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >MH (Maria)</div>
      <div id="bus23" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >P101</div>
      <div id="bus24" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >P102</div>
      <div id="bus25" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >P103</div>
      <div id="bus26" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >P104</div>
      <div id="bus27" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >P105</div>
      <div id="bus28" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >PEQ</div>
      <div id="bus29" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Rand</div>
      <div id="bus30" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >Rox</div>
      <div id="bus31" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >RK</div>
      <div id="bus32" class = "element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >WM</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
let offset = [0, 0]

function allowDrop(ev) {
  var t = ev.target; // each parking spot is ev.target/t
  while (t !== null && !t.classList.contains("target")) {
    t = t.parentNode;
  }
  if (t && t.childNodes.length > 1) { //how many buses can go in each spot (only lets two busses per parking spot)
    return false;
  }
  ev.preventDefault()
}

function drag(ev) { //bus name being dragged
  ev.dataTransfer.setData('dragID', ev.target.id) // changes the drag area to the drop text and pic
  offset = [
    ev.target.offsetLeft - ev.clientX,
    ev.target.offsetTop - ev.clientY
  ] 
}

function drop(ev) { //bus name being dropped
  ev.preventDefault()
  const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('dragID') // transfers image
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)) // changes the child event

  var direction = ev.target.getAttribute('data-name'); //gets direction from html
  if(direction == "left"){ // changes pic depending on direction
    ev.target.style.backgroundImage = "url('busLeft.png')";  // left bus
    ev.target.style.backgroundSize = "75%"; 
    ev.target.style.border = "none"; 
  }else if(direction == "right"){
    ev.target.style.backgroundImage = "url('busRight.png')"; // right bus
    ev.target.style.backgroundSize = "75%";
    ev.target.style.border = "none"; 
  }else if(direction == "down"){
    ev.target.style.backgroundImage = "url('busDown.png')"; // down bus
    ev.target.style.backgroundSize = "55%";
    ev.target.style.border = "none"; 
  }else{
    ev.target.style.border = "1px solid black"; //busses that are not in parking spots (to the right)
  }
  
  ev.target.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"; //ensures bus image won't repeat
}

function dragLeave(ev) {
  if (ev.target.className == "target" ) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("element").innerHTML = "Left the dropzone";
    ev.target.style.backgroundImage = "";
    ev.target.style.border = "1px solid black"; 
  }
}
```

Sample Link:
https://mcstbusparkingextraspots.caitlynpl.repl.co/

Thank you so much for any feedback!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to call a new function at the end of drop(ev), that checks, if a target div has a children or not. if there is no child, remove any background.

the problem is, that the removal of a background image only happens if there is a drag leave event, which does not always happen.

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL7pjg1r/1/), i added a function to check if there is a chilren in any parking lot and if not, set the style to default. The function will be called at the end of every drop call. this is only one possible solution to this problem.

```
function checkChildren() {
    const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("target");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(collection, (element) => {
        if (element.children.length == 0) {
            element.style.backgroundImage = "";
            element.style.border = "1px solid black"; 
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea I noticed that too. I just tried to add this check and it doesn't fire when it's used in drop(ev). I wonder if the same concept could be used somewhere else in the code where it would work

Comment: i edited my initial answer.

Comment: I just checked it out, and it works perfectly! Thank you so much :-))